# Better way to bulk insert in sqlite3 C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I've bulk insert statements to be executed. I can create a single sql string with all the insert statements and execute once like,

```
std::string sql_string = "";
int i;
for(i=0;i<1000; i++) {
   Transaction transaction = transactions[i];
   std::string tx_sql = CREATE_SQL_STRING(transaction, lastTxId); // "INSERT INTO (...) VALUES (...);"
   sql_string = sql_string+tx_sql;
   lastTxId++;
}
sqlite3_exec(db, sql_string.c_str(), callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
```

Is there any other better-performing way to bulk insert with sqlite3 c++ API?

Insertions are not security critical. Only the performance is considered. Should I use prepared statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most important: put all inserts into a single transaction.

for more detailed stuff regarding performance see the official documentation: https://sqlite.org/speed.html (a bit outdated)

for more recent information i'd recomment https://medium.com/@JasonWyatt/squeezing-performance-from-sqlite-insertions-971aff98eef2

as for prepared statements: i am not sure about performance, but it is a good practice to always use them.